# Interval Vue.js not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am new to Vuejs. I am trying to set a interval to a function. Unfortunately It doesn't work. I get the following error out of it:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'unshift' of undefined

Just a regular alert box IS working. So I guess the variable can't be accessed. How can I access the variable of `message`? I added a jsfiddle below.

JS

```
new Vue({

    el: '#app',

    data: {


        message: {message: '', name: '', fblike: 0, share: 0, retweets: 0, likes: 0, image: '', adress: '', platform: 'tw'},

        messages: [

            {message: 'Lorem ipsum', name: 'John Doe', fblike: 0, share: 0, retweets: 1, likes: 0, image: '', adress: '', platform: 'tw'},
            {message: 'Lorem ipsum', name: 'John Doe', fblike: 0, share: 0, retweets: 1, likes: 0, image: '', adress: '', platform: 'fb'},


        ],

        headerShow: false,
        programShow: false,
        sliderShow: true

    },

    methods: {

        addTweet: function() {
            if(this.message.message){
                this.messages.unshift(this.message);
                this.message = {message: '', name: '', fblike: 0, share: 0, retweets: 0, likes: 0, image: '', adress: '', platform: 'tw'};
            }
        },

        setTweet: function() {

            setInterval(function() {
                this.message = {message: '', name: '', fblike: 0, share: 0, retweets: 0, likes: 0, image: '', adress: '', platform: 'tw'};
                this.messages.unshift(this.message);
            }, 5000);


        }



    }

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fLj5ac0L/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you lost the correct context into the `setInterval`, so this is not bounded to Vue object and `this.message` would return undefined.You can use arrow function to solve this, or keep context inside the another variable.

```
setTweet: function() {

    setInterval(() => {
        this.message = {message: '', name: '', fblike: 0, share: 0, retweets: 0, likes: 0, image: '', adress: '', platform: 'tw'};
        this.messages.unshift(this.message);
    }, 5000);


}
```

or

```
setTweet: function() {
    var self = this;
    setInterval(function() {
        self.message = {message: '', name: '', fblike: 0, share: 0, retweets: 0, likes: 0, image: '', adress: '', platform: 'tw'};
        self.messages.unshift(self.message);
    }, 5000);


}
```

Comment: Already thought that something like that was the problem. But, I know now what the exact problem is. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can NOT use this in function(){} to call outside variables, the function(){} create a new scope, you can modify you code like this:

```
setTweet: function() {
  var that = this;
  setInterval(function() {
    that.message = {message: '', name: '', fblike: 0, share: 0, retweets: 0, likes: 0, image: '', adress: '', platform: 'tw'};
    that.messages.unshift(this.message);
  }, 5000);
}
```

or you can use arrow function like this:

```
setTweet: function() {
  setInterval(() => {
    this.message = {message: '', name: '', fblike: 0, share: 0, retweets: 0, likes: 0, image: '', adress: '', platform: 'tw'};
    this.messages.unshift(this.message);
  }, 5000);
}
```

You can get more about JavaScript variable scope on this question: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: U forgot to set the `unshift(this.message);` to `unshift(that.message);`. Thanks anyway! And also thanks for the link. I will look into it.